# Why am I getting the error ValueError: Expected input batch_size (4) to match target batch_size (64)?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, mnist

Why am I getting the error `ValueError: Expected input batch_size (4) to match target batch_size (64)`?

Is it something to do with an incorrect number of channels(?) in the first linear layer? In this example I have 128 *4 *4 as the channel.

I have tried looking online and on this site for the answer but I have not been able to find it. So, I asked here.

Here is the network:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    """A representation of a convolutional neural network comprised of VGG blocks."""
    def __init__(self, n_channels):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # VGG block 1
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(n_channels, 64, (3,3))
        self.act1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d((2,2), stride=(2,2))
        # VGG block 2
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, (3,3))
        self.act2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d((2,2), stride=(2,2))
        # VGG block 3
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, (3,3))
        self.act3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d((2,2), stride=(2,2))
        # Fully connected layer
        self.f1 = nn.Linear(128 * 4 * 4, 1000)
        self.act4 = nn.ReLU()
        # Output layer
        self.f2 = nn.Linear(1000, 10)
        self.act5 = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, X):
        """This function forward propagates the input."""
        # VGG block 1
        X = self.conv1(X)
        X = self.act1(X)
        X = self.pool1(X)
        # VGG block 2
        X = self.conv2(X)
        X = self.act2(X)
        X = self.pool2(X)
        # VGG block 3
        X = self.conv3(X)
        X = self.act3(X)
        X = self.pool3(X)
        # Flatten
        X = X.view(-1, 128 * 4 * 4)
        # Fully connected layer
        X = self.f1(X)
        X = self.act4(X)
        # Output layer
        X = self.f2(X)
        X = self.act5(X)

        return X
```

Here is the training loop:

```
def training_loop(
        n_epochs,
        optimizer,
        model,
        loss_fn,
        train_loader):
    for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
        loss_train = 0.0
        for i, (imgs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):

            outputs = model(imgs)

            loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            loss.backward()

            optimizer.step()

            loss_train += loss.item()

        if epoch == 1 or epoch % 10 == 0:
            print('{} Epoch {}, Training loss {}'.format(
                datetime.datetime.now(),
                epoch,
                loss_train / len(train_loader)))
```

Comment: What is the shape of the input data, target data and the output of the model (if the error occurred after the forward pass)?

Comment: The input data is (1,28,28) which is also the output data I think. How do print the shape of X in `forward`? I tried adding a print function and then `net = Net(1); net.forward()` but this didn’t print the shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're getting the dimensions wrong. From the error and your comment, I take it that your input is of the shape `(64, 1, 28, 28)`.

Now, the shape of `X` at `X = self.pool3(X)` is `(64, 128, 1, 1)`, which you then reshaped on the next line to `(4, 128 * 4 * 4)`.

Long story short, the output of your model is `(4, 10)` i.e batch_size `(4)`, which you're comparing on this line `loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)` with a tensor of batch_size `(64)` as the error said.

I don't know what you're trying to do but I'm guessing that you'd want to change this line `self.f1 = nn.Linear(128 * 4 * 4, 1000)` to this `self.f1 = nn.Linear(128 * 1 * 1, 1000)`

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thank you! How did you figure out the `128 * 1 * 1` calculation? If you printed the shape of `X` at `X = self.pool3(X)` how did you print the shape?

Comment: This should answer that, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580088/calculate-the-output-size-in-convolution-layer

Comment: You can add a `print` statement after the line like this, `print(X.shape)`.

Answer (score 1):

As nerveless_child said, your dimensions are off!

For the other folks who are reviewing / studying Neural Networks, more generally, you can calculate the output dimension of a single convolutional layer by

`[(W−K+2P)/S]+1`

where

```
W is the input volume - in your case you have not given us this
K is the Kernel size - in your case 2 == "filter" 
P is the padding - in your case 2
S is the stride - in your case 3
```

Another, prettier formulation:

[image: The prettied-up equation]