# mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x4 and 128x64)

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Could not find out why the mat1 from the convolutional network is 128x4 and not 4x128. The following is the convolutional network used:

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
torch.nn.Conv2d(2,32,kernel_size=3,padding=1),
torch.nn.ReLU(),
torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),

torch.nn.Conv2d(32,64,kernel_size=3,padding=1),
torch.nn.ReLU(),
torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),

torch.nn.Conv2d(64,128,kernel_size=3,padding=1),
torch.nn.ReLU(),
torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2,2,padding=1),
torch.nn.Flatten(),

torch.nn.Linear(128, 64),
torch.nn.ReLU(),
torch.nn.Linear(64,4)
)
```

The model training code is as follows:

```
epochs = 1000
losses = [] #A
for i in range(epochs): #B
    game = Gridworld(size=size, mode='static') #C
    # state_ = game.board.render_np().reshape(1,l1) + np.random.rand(1,l1)/10.0 #D
    state_ = game.board.render_np() + np.random.rand(size,size)/10.0 #D
    state1 = torch.from_numpy(state_).float() #E
    print(state1.shape)
    status = 1 #F
    while(status == 1): #G
        qval = model(state1) #H
        qval_ = qval.data.numpy()
        if (random.random() < epsilon): #I
            action_ = np.random.randint(0,4)
        else:
            action_ = np.argmax(qval_)
       
        action = action_set[action_] #J
        game.makeMove(action) #K
        state2_ = game.board.render_np().reshape(1,l1) + np.random.rand(1,l1)/10.0
        state2 = torch.from_numpy(state2_).float() #L
        reward = game.reward()
        with torch.no_grad():
            newQ = model(state2.reshape(1,l1))
        maxQ = torch.max(newQ) #M
        if reward == -1: #N
            Y = reward + (gamma * maxQ)
        else:
            Y = reward
        Y = torch.Tensor([Y]).detach()
        X = qval.squeeze()[action_] #O
        loss = loss_fn(X, Y) #P
        print(i, loss.item())
        clear_output(wait=True)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        losses.append(loss.item())
        optimizer.step()
        state1 = state2
        if reward != -1: #Q
            status = 0
    if epsilon > 0.1: #R
        epsilon -= (1/epochs)
```

The error log shown is:

```
torch.Size([2, 12, 12])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-d2f43f09fd01> in <module>()
     74     status = 1 #F
     75     while(status == 1): #G
---> 76         qval = model(state1) #H
     77         qval_ = qval.data.numpy()
     78         if (random.random() < epsilon): #I

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    101 
    102     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 103         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    104 
    105     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x4 and 128x64)
```

mat1 should be the output of the convolutional network after it is flattened, and mat2 is the linear network following it.
Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the input matrix dimensions? Also, what's mat1? Are you getting any errors? If so, please post the logs

Comment: @helloworld Hi, updated the question with error log and model training codes. Input state has shape [2, 12, 12].

Comment: The input dimensions are still unclear. Could you post the shape of the tensor `state1`?

Comment: @helloworld Hi, is it the output of print(state1.shape)? it is torch.Size([2, 12, 12]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the output shapes for each layer

```
Conv2d(2,32,kernel_size=3,padding=1)   # 32x12x12
MaxPool2d(2,2)                         # 32x6x6
Conv2d(32,64,kernel_size=3,padding=1)  # 64x6x6
MaxPool2d(2,2)                         # 64x3x3
Conv2d(64,128,kernel_size=3,padding=1) # 128x3x3
MaxPool2d(2,2,padding=1)               # 128x2x2
Flatten()                              # 128x4
```

You'll need to change the kernel parameters and padding sizes if you wish to obtain an output of a given shape. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580088/calculate-the-output-size-in-convolution-layer) might help in calculating the output shapes after each layer.

Another approach is that you could take a transpose of the flattened array and pass it into the Linear layers. You'll need to add the line in your forward function like below

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class NN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
      super(NN, self).__init__()
      
      self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
          torch.nn.Conv2d(2,32,kernel_size=3,padding=1),
          torch.nn.ReLU(),
          torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2,2))

      self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
          torch.nn.Conv2d(32,64,kernel_size=3,padding=1),
          torch.nn.ReLU(),
          torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2,2))
      
      self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
          torch.nn.Conv2d(64,128,kernel_size=3,padding=1),
          torch.nn.ReLU(),
          torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2,2,padding=1))
      
      self.flattened_tensor = nn.Flatten()

      self.linear_layer = nn.Sequential(
          torch.nn.Linear(128, 64),
          torch.nn.ReLU(),
          torch.nn.Linear(64,4)
      )
    
  def forward(self, inp):
    conv_output = self.layer3(self.layer2(self.layer1(inp)))
    flattened_output = self.flattened_tensor(conv_output)
    
    transposed_matrix = torch.transpose(flattened_output, 0, 1)
    
    linear_output = self.linear_layer(transposed_matrix)
    return linear_output

model = NN()
output = model(arr)
```

Comment: I'd like to try the transpose method. It seems I can't simply add torch.transpose(0, 1) inside the model definition.

Comment: or you can change the last but one fc layer torch.nn.Linear(128, 64) -> torch.nn.Linear(128*2*2, 64)

Comment: @TQCH yes I have tried that, but the error becomes: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x4 and 512x64)

Comment: @Danny, I've added another approach via which you can transpose the intermediate matrix

Comment: @Danny Did you remove the Flatten layer? If you keep nn.Flatten(start_dim=1), then the shape pre-fc(512, 64) should be (batch_size, 512).

Comment: @TQCH strange, when I removed the flatten function, the error message now becomes:
mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (256x2 and 512x64)